# How do I remove all questions from a text with regex and stringr?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

*edit to demonstrate I made an effort to solve this myself*

I have the following string:

```
"This is a question? This is an answer This is another question? This is another answer."
```

What I want to do is create a regex that will match all the questions so I can remove them. In this case the preceding answer or sentence doesn't always end with a '.' (full stop). So what I am looking for is to match sentences that end with a question mark and start with a capital letter.

What I want to match:

```
"This is a question?" and "This is another question?"
```

I work in R so I prefer an answer with stringr, but I'm mostly interested in the regex that I should apply.

I tried the following regex `^[A-Z].+\?` but unfortunately it matches the whole string.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?  https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I tried this: ^[A-Z].+\?

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick in regex: `([A-Z][^A-Z?]*\?)`